# Локальные переменные

Tags: delphi

Есть ли способ в Delphi не дать уничтожиться локальной переменной функции после её завершения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нет, конечно же!** Можно лишь скопировать значение локальной переменной в глобальную. Это, по сути, и будет самым простым решением. Или же вы можете передать переменную в процедуру/функцию с помощью ключевого слова **var** или **out**. Но все равно, все переменные, объявленные в процедуре/функции **уничтожаются** после завершения работы функции.

**Это аксиома!**

Comment: Костылями можно.

Answer (score 3):

Можно. Но это скорее костыль.
Называется "типизированная константа"

```
procedure my_proc; 
 const i:Integer=0;
begin 
   inc(i); 
   if i>=10 Then .... 
 end;

begin 
   for j:=0 To 19 Do 
     my_proc; 
 end.
```